# angular-tanslate with dropdown doesn't work under Chromium

Tags: angularjs, html-select, chromium, angular-translate

I have translated an application. If i use `<ul>` for the language select, everything is working fine. When i switch to `<select>`, then i have problems under chromium. But with Firefox is still working fine. Here 2 code fragments:

1. HTML part

```html
<select id="SelectLang" ng-controller="LanguageSelectController">
  <option ng-click="changeLang('de_DE')">{{'LANGUAGE_FIELD_GERMAN'|translate}}</option>
  <option ng-click="changeLang('en_EN')">{{'LANGUAGE_FIELD_ENGLISH'|translate}}</option>
</select>
```

2. JS Part

```js
app.controller('LanguageSelectController', function ($scope, $translate) {
    $scope.changeLang = function (key) {
        $translate.use(key).then(function (key) {
            console.log("Sprache zu " + key + " gewechselt.");
    }, function (key) {
            console.log("Irgendwas lief schief.");
        });
    };
});
```

Does anyone have the same problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a plunker or anything that shows the problem?

Comment: Nope, but i will try to build one example...

Comment: Sorry, the example is not working in plunker :( here the code: http://plnkr.co/edit/8I0GAQnPpKrukFz4IOMT?p=info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a look at your plunker, I have updated it with a working version:

http://plnkr.co/edit/6P4V5qD7SIcTdKpYxWm2?p=preview

There were a few things that were possibly causing the issue. I have put comments in the plunker with the changes, as well as listed them below. The files to look at are `script.js` and `index.html`.

The thing that is missing from your plunker is that you have not defined an `ng-app` attribute in the html. I added `ng-app="app"` to the body element. Without this, the angular app will not bootstrap. So none of your angular was being executed.

There was also a missing closing bracket at the end of the config block, this could just be when you were writing the plunker, but it might have also caused problems.

Lastly, the `script.js` file needs to be loaded after the `angular.js` file. Otherwise angular is not defined at the point that script.js is parsed.

**Edit:**

I have updated the plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/54Fk0uP9jn8CzmDnNZNr?p=preview

I think I had misunderstood the problem. The problem was with how the `select` element was being written. It would seem that the `ng-click` on the `option` elements wasn't firing in chrome. Using an `ng-change` on the `select` element itself, and having an `ng-model` on the element works around this problem. It also cleans up the html a little and makes it easier to extend with more options.

Comment: thanks a lot. The example is working :) but only in Firefox, not Chromium...this is exactly the behavior i have in my application.

Comment: I have updated the answer with an edit. And an explanation of the issue.